# Record and play BAG file

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have a question about an error message.

this tutorial

http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData

I tried and it worked with the test bag .

but when I tried to play my own bag file appeared the error message

TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame at time .....

where could be the problem , have already searched a lot but have not yet found the right answer .

many thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211080/record-and-play-bag-file/) by [Kartierung_ss15](https://answers.ros.org/users/22751/kartierung_ss15/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I hope this is your issue, as it's easy to fix: make sure and pay attention to item #4 in that tutorial. Data in bag files often contains timestamps; running without setting the `use_sim_time` parameter to `true` often presents TF errors.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2015-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0